# Función con cambio de fuente en VBA

Tags: excel, vba, función-personalizada, fuentes

Entiendo que una función en Excel cumple que unas celdas (o valores) de entradas se vuelven salidas a través de un algoritmo... yo estoy programando funciones personalizadas por `VBA Excel` y quisiera saber si:

**¿Podría hacer una función que aparte de dar un resultado, también lo de con un formato: por ejemplo subrayado y negrita?**

Más específicamente, se crea una función "sumita" con dos valores de entrada y cuya salida es la suma de esos dos valores:

```vba
Function sumita (by N1, N2 as double) as double
     sumita = N1 + N2
End Function
```

Quiero saber si además de obtener esa suma, podría obtenerla con un formato (`font.bold = true, font.underline = true`).

PD: no me digan que lo ponga con fuentes normal de Excel Básico, eso ya lo se, quiero saber si podría programar una función así como se programa un procedimiento (`Sub()`).

---

Para que puedan entender mi problema, yo estoy programando funciones personalizadas con respuestas en varias celdas, la primera es el título y deseo que se resalte al demás texto. Como ejemplo tengo este:

```vba
Function Cal_arit(selection As Range)
  s = WorksheetFunction.Sum(selection)
  p = WorksheetFunction.Average(selection)
  Dim R(1 To 3, 0)
    R(1, 0) = "Cálculo aritmético"
    R(2, 0) = "La suma es: " & s
    R(3, 0) = "El promedio es: " & p
  Cal_arit = R
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez esto te sirva :

```vb
 Sub FormatoCelda(ByVal Celda As String)
    Range(Celda).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    Range(Celda).Font.Bold = True
 End Sub
```

En esta función, sólo tienes que pasarle como parámetro el nombre de la celda, donde pondrás el resultado,  por ejemplo "A1"

Comment: Con base en la información agregada por el OP, este código no es útil para el caso específico pues se trata de un sub procedure y no de una función.

Comment: Es corrrecta tu afirmación, sólo que al principio cuando formuló la pregunta no publicó el código de la función, ni tampoco especificó que se tratara de una función matricial.  Las funciones que el usuario defina y que devuelven un valor, no pueden cambiar el formato, del libro o la hoja en la que se esté trabajando, tendria que ser un procedimiento para poder hacerlo, o irse por el lado del formato condicional. PD. No había visto tu comentario más abajo Rubén!.. Totalmente de acuerdo

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones personalizadas sólo pueden devolver valores, no pueden afectar las propiedades de la celda en la que se encuentra la función ni de otras celdas, entre otras limitaciones.

De [Descripción de las limitaciones de las funciones personalizadas en Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel)

> Una función definida por el usuario llamada por una fórmula de una
>   celda de hoja de cálculo no puede cambiar el entorno de Microsoft
>   Excel. Esto significa que este tipo de función no puede hacer nada de
>   lo siguiente:
>
> - Insertar, eliminar o dar formato a celdas de la hoja de cálculo.
> - Cambiar el valor de otra celda.
> - Mover, cambiar el nombre, eliminar o agregar hojas a un libro.
> - Cambiar cualquiera de las opciones del entorno, como el modo de cálculo o las vistas de la pantalla.
> - Agregar nombres a un libro.
> - Establecer propiedades o ejecutar la mayoría de los métodos.